# CUDA failed to launch kernel : no kernel image available for execution

Tags: cuda, gpu, driver, nvidia

i am trying to run CUDA on a rather old GPU. I tried the CUDA Samples vectorAdd which gives me the following error:

```
Failed to launch vectorAdd kernel (error code no kernel image is available for execution on the device)!
```

These are the outputs from

1. deviceQuery:

```
CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 580"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.1 / 9.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 1467 MBytes (1538392064 bytes)
MapSMtoCores for SM 2.0 is undefined.  Default to use 64 Cores/SM
MapSMtoCores for SM 2.0 is undefined.  Default to use 64 Cores/SM
  (16) Multiprocessors, ( 64) CUDA Cores/MP:     1024 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1630 MHz (1.63 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             2050 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              384-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 786432 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65535), 3D=(2048, 2048, 2048)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 32768
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1536
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (65535, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Supports Cooperative Kernel Launch:            No
  Supports MultiDevice Co-op Kernel Launch:      No
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 3 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 9.1, CUDA Runtime Version = 9.0, NumDevs = 1
Result = PASS
```

2. nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.147                Driver Version: 390.147                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 580     Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 42%   48C   P12    N/A /  N/A |    257MiB /  1467MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

3. nvcc --version

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
```

Now according to the CUDA compatibility PDF
https://docs.nvidia.com/pdf/CUDA_Compatibility.pdf
I assume I have Binary Compatibility from CUDA 9.0.176 to the GPU Driver.
For Compute Capability Support, the table does not list the 390 Driver.
Is it even possible to program CUDA on this GPU or should I get a newer one? If it is possible, what combination of driver and CUDA toolkit version do I need?

Comment: You are not compiling for the compute capability of your GPU. In the compilation flags, there is `-gencode=arch=compute_xx,code=sm_xx` and the particular `xx` of your GPU is not being created. Its not "the driver" its the GPU. Check which GPU it has, then find which CC it has, and thus flag that one.

Comment: CUDA 9 dropped support for Fermi (sm_20) architecture. You need CUDA 8 (its deprecated but still available there). That is an ancient GPU.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. I did not see that anywhere. I got it working with CUDA 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPU you are using is a Fermi class (compute capability 2.0) device. Support was [officially removed](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/9.0/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#unsupported-features) from the CUDA toolkit when CUDA 9.0 was released in September 2017. The last release of the CUDA toolkit with Fermi support was CUDA 8.0. You will have to use that (or something even older) if you wish to use that GPU with CUDA.

[Answer assembled from comments an added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag]